# Mapping A point from one 3D Coordinate System to Another 3D coordinate System with Euler Angles between the two systems given

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, coordinate-systems, 3d

Suppose I have a point in the green coordinate system, and I wish to describe it in reference to the orange coordinate system. I know the roll, pitch, and yaw of the green system with respect to the orange system. I also know the x,y,z values of a point in the green system and wish to get (x',y',z') which is the point values with respect to the orange system. How would I do so?[image: The two coordinate systems]

If it is possible to solve this with rotational transformation matrices I would like to know the procedure. I am aware of the rotational transformations for roll, pitch and yaw, but the output value differs based on the order of these matrices since matrix multiplication is non-commutative. Is there a way to get (x',y',z') with just the information that I've given? I don't mind not using rotational transformation matrices as long as I can get the output with only the roll pitch and yaw given.

Comment: Have a look at the superimposition matrix at [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html).

Comment: There have been many posts about this topic, for example [Rotation matrix convention; successive rotations in intermediate coordinate systems or not](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/506902/139123). The order of matrix multiplication matters for much the same reason that the order you apply roll, pitch, and yaw matters. There is a standard sequence of roll, pitch, yaw in aeronautics, so if that's what you're using, you can try [How can a 3D rotational transformation between two cartesian coordinate systems be performed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2276647/139123).